# Best way to contact a possible employer

Tags: applications, email

I found online a foreign company I am interested in (I'm a few months away from graduation).

Their website is one page per each sector they work in, and each shows an online form to contact the manager of that branch. The only other contact available is a *namecompany@namecompany.domain* address.

They have a "submit an application" page but it is in their own language and seems too "official". I would just ask for general information on entry-level positions, internships and so on.

**Should I contact the manager individually or e-mail the generic address?**

I would not want to annoy the managers who probably have better things to do, but I am afraid that my e-mail will get lost if I send it to the company address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the position, really.
To name an example, when I was a teacher I would get invited to interviews more often when I called first to ask who to contact, before sending the E-mail.
I can imagine this would work for sales as well, since communication skills are necessary.
In software however, I would do it the other way around and send a message to the general address (the info@ one) and if I didn't hear anything I would call and ask if they had gotten my message.

But getting back to your question for internships I would go with the "generic" address (I have always done that at least).
For entry positions (employment) use their forms, unless you can't read it because of the foreign language, then I would recommend to play safe and send the mail to the generic address ;).

Comment: Interesting take. I'm a chemical/process engineer, so not really "sales" and not really "software development"; I fall somewhere in the middle of those two spheres :)
I'm going to go with the generic address, the company seems friendly enough that they can find the time to redirect me to the right person or form if I misjudged the address.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any issue with language then you can use the google chrome browser to translate what's on the screen. It's not an accurate translation but can get you there. 
You can also try reaching their official outreach channel on LinkedIn if they have a profile there. Usually they have some one from HR on LinkedIn for their company. Reaching them there has helped with getting responses to contacts in some cases.
Finally you can always ask for a harmless contact info via Twitter as well. But beware of how you phrase your question.

Disclaimer: I do not work for Google, Google Translate, LinkedIn or Twitter, also I am not in the ad industry as well. So pardon if it feels like an ad.